# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'updateWorldMatrix')

Tags: three.js, 3d-model

I am not very skilled in ThreeJS.

I am trying to create bounding box to wrap a 3D model. The model is loaded well because I can see it on the scene

```
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
loader.load(
  modelsPath[ 0 ],
  ( gltf ) => {
    mesh = gltf.scene;
    mesh.visible = false;
    mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
    scene.add( mesh );
    box1 = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( mesh.asset );
    group.add( box1 );
  },
  null,
  function ( error ) {
    console.log( error );
  }
);
```

but when I use `box1 = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( mesh.asset );` I got the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'updateWorldMatrix')
at Box3.expandByObject (Box3.js:160:1)
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: I also tried  `box1 = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( mesh );` but I get an error

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
let mesh;
let bb;

loader.load("REACT.glb", (gltf) => {
  mesh = gltf.scene;
  scene.add(mesh);
  bb = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(mesh);
  const boxHelper = new THREE.Box3Helper(bb, 0x00ff00);
  scene.add(boxHelper);
});
```

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/helpers/BoxHelper

and BTW how can you see mesh, when you set visibility property to mesh in `false`? O_o

```
 mesh.visible = false;
```

Comment: I got  `THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D.`. The visibility is set in render function according to certain conditions. After loading I need to hide it.

Comment: Could you show full code, because I dont have any erreors?

Answer (score 0):

The [Box3](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Box3) is a Mathematical object and not a `Object3D` meaning it can't be added to a `Scene` object.
The reference you are looking for is [BoxHelper](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/helpers/BoxHelper), as follow:

```
const box = new THREE.BoxHelper(model, 0xff0000);
scene.add(box);
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/trinketmage/pen/LYajJxY?editors=0010)

Comment: I noticed that... we wrote a comment together about the same topic some time ago... and thus we met here again, as if we were led by a pet crow and a pet jackdaw...

Comment: I am getting this: `Uncaught TypeError: box.isEmpty is not a function` even using the model you provided in the working example..

Comment: `.isEmpty` is a method available only on "abstract" math object like [`Box3`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=box3#api/en/math/Box3.isEmpty) (they are not on [Object3D](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=boxHelper#api/en/core/Object3D)), meaning you are probably still using method(s) related to `Box3` inside your code, you need to remove them.

Comment: Please note that without sandbox it is really hard to help without any way to reproduce.
And that [BoxHelper](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=boxh#api/en/helpers/BoxHelper) (used for bounding box visualisation for general object) differs from
 [Box3Helper](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/helpers/Box3Helper) that help visualise a [Box3](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=box3#api/en/math/Box3).